# Generating a list of page numbers for a web page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, loops, razor

I am trying to add paging to a website by showing 10 numbers at the top of each page. I wrote this code to generate the 10 numbers that correspond to each page

```
@for (int i = (Math.Ceiling( page / 10 - 1) * 10 ) + 1; i <= Math.Ceiling( page / 10 - 1) * 10 + 10 ; i++)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "ShowItems", page = i.ToString() })
        @Html.Raw(",");
    }
```

This works fine except for the end. For example if I have 12 pages, paging will show

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
```

For all pages between 1-10 and then will show

```
 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

For the pages 11 and 12.

I need to change my loop to something that stops the counter at the last page.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

P.S I don't want to use `PagedList` as I am dealing with huge data and can't load it at one.

Comment: maybe this is a dumb comment. But why are you not just looping like this:
@for (int i = 1; i <= page; i++)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "ShowItems", page = i.ToString() })
        @Html.Raw(",");
    }

Comment: PagedList has an extension method on IQueryable so that when you are dealing with a large amount of data you don't need to load it all.  Also, if you want to handle the paging yourself, you could create a `StaticPagedList`, and still use the PagedList pager.

Comment: @RonaDona posted you reusable paging solution for asp.net mvc .

Comment: @cadrell Thanks for the info. Just checked it and you're right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, I'd advise you to extract the "start" and "end" parts out into local variables first. It'll make it *much* easier to debug. So your existing code would become (ignoring Razor syntax for now):

```
int startPage = (Math.Ceiling(page / 10 - 1) * 10) + 1;
int endPage = Math.Ceiling(page / 10 - 1) * 10 + 10;
for (int i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++)
```

I'd then extract use the fact that you've already done most of the work for computing `endPage` to compute `startPage`:

```
int startPage = (Math.Ceiling(page / 10 - 1) * 10) + 1;
int endPage = startPage + 9;
for (int i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++)
```

Now you just need to cap it to the number of pages:

```
int startPage = (Math.Ceiling(page / 10 - 1) * 10) + 1;
int endPage = Math.Min(startPage + 9, totalPages);
for (int i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++)
```

Comment: @WaqasRaja: Part of the point of the post is to explain the diagnostic process. The OP's code didn't contain `Math.Floor`, so the first step of extracting to local variables shouldn't either. Additionally, your replacement didn't give the same result. For example, if `page` is 10, then `(Math.Ceiling(page / 10 -1) * 10) + 1` returns 1, whereas `(Math.Floor(page / 10) * 10) + 1` returns 11.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a method to do that a while ago

```
private IEnumerable<int> GetPaginationInfo(int total, int itemsPerPage, int currentPage, int rangeBeforeAndAfter = 2)
{
    int minPage = 0;
    int maxPage = ((int)Math.Ceiling((double)(((double)total) / ((double)itemsPerPage)))) - 1;
    int beginPage = currentPage - rangeBeforeAndAfter;
    int endPage = currentPage + rangeBeforeAndAfter;
    if (beginPage < minPage)
    {
        endPage += -beginPage;
        beginPage = minPage;
    }
    if (endPage > maxPage)
    {
        beginPage -= endPage - maxPage;
        if (beginPage < minPage)
        {
            beginPage = minPage;
        }
        endPage = maxPage;
    }
    return Enumerable.Range(beginPage + 1, (endPage + 1) - beginPage);
}
```

Call

```
GetPaginationInfo(100, 10, 0, 5);
```

Comment: Note: this generates 11 items (odd number), so the current page will be the on in the center

Answer (score -1):

You could just use mod (%) to find the remainder and as those as the last pages.

as in

12 % 10 = 2.  So the last section will have 2 pages.